# Import file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Firstly, I Want to read excel file which user is uploading and saving data to DB.
I have tried load function using excel API.

```
Excel::load($file_name_real, function($input) {
              $results = $input->all();
//              $input->dump();
        })->download('xls');
```

But its not happening So now I want to move File to server then will read file then will unlink. By following function

```
$input1->move('/laravel');
```

But its not moving file.

Comment: Do you have permission to write to the `/laravel` directory? Are there any exceptions thrown when trying to move the file? Provide more info.